# Problems binding a static library (.a)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to figure out how to create a working binding project for a static library I have. We didn't create the static library ourselves but we have rights to use it.

I have tried to follow the steps on this page without success: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/

Basically what happened was that when running the command 'sharpie bind --sdk=iphoneos9.3 *.a' I got a list of errors (see bottom of the post)
 So after playing around with this for a bunch of hours, I decided to read the ApiDefinition. Apparently the process described in the guide linked above, is deprecated and I should add the .a file as a Native Reference.

And based on the comments in the ApiDefinition, we have to create the bindings manually. The problem is, I don't know the method names inside the library. Also, even if I did, the library is huge (header file of our desktop version was already 36k lines).

Could someone tell us how to proceed?

list of errors from sharpie command:

```
Macbook-Pro:iossdk researchdevelopment$ sharpie bind --sdk=iphoneos9.3 libHCNetSDK_sim.a
Parsing 1 header files...
warning: /Users/researchdevelopment/Desktop/iossdk/libHCNetSDK_sim.a: 'linker' input unused
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-c'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-spell-checking'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Xclang -detailed-preprocessing-record'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-D NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=9.3'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include'
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1'
error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
Error while processing /Users/researchdevelopment/Desktop/iossdk/libHCNetSDK_sim.a.

Submitting usage data to Xamarin...
Submitted - thank you for helping to improve Objective Sharpie!

Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: Clang failed to parse input and exited with code 1
```

Comment: Do you have access to the header file/files for the native library? Objective Sharpie parses these header files to extract the method signatures to generate the ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs files

Comment: I do have header files but Objective Sharpie can't seem to parse them. I tried modifying the header files and removing parts, but all it generates then is a StructsAndEnums.cs and no ApiDefinition.cs . Any clue on why it does this? Could fixing this also fix my main problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pass the .a file to Objective Sharpie. When I last built a binding project, I followed [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/advanced/).

About half way through, there is an example of how to run Objective Sharpie to generate the binding, which passes the headers only, not the compiled binary.

Comment: The thing with that is that it only generates a StructsAndEnums.cs for me. Even after stripping down the header file to 2 method calls, it doesn't create an ApiDefinition.cs

Comment: I figured it's because we're doing PInvokes and not doing a normal binding.